# Corrupt effects in awn and gnome do after intel graphic driver upgrade

Tags: intel-graphics

I've upgraded my intel HD graphic driver to the 2.16.0 version, all work fine but AWN and gnome pie icon effects is going like these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

what should I do ? thanks.
my laptop: dell 1464, core i3 intel HD.
sorry about my english

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).